# How to save asp files as asp format not sln

Tags: c#, asp.net

Problem with Visual Studio  in the design of the asp pages save as .sln files 
I am a Beginner in asp programming language and I have a problem in Save projects :
it always save as sln files and I want to save the pages asp format 
Note
I'm working on Facebook applications using asp.net c#
Is this a relationship with my problem?

I am a Beginner  in English as well as you can see ^_^

Comment: When you create any kind of project in Visual Studio, it puts it in a `.sln` file to organize it. Not sure why you think it saves your `.asp` pages as `.sln`.

Comment: If i want to upload the page in hosting I can not upload sln file !

Comment: Please clarify the actual issue in the question then.

Comment: What does ASP.NET MVC have to do with your question?

Comment: I'm not good at English, but I will try to explain to you
I want to upload the pages in the Hosting sites
And it must be in .asp format 
I do not know how to get on the asp file I Just get on the sln file

Comment: If you dont want the solution file because you are creating a regular website, you'll have to do just that. VS -> Create new web site, and not project.

Comment: I already designed Facebook app project as sln How can I save it in asp format ??

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are getting confused with the files, .sln files are extension for solution files that Visual Studio makes when u creates a project. A solution can have multiple projects and a project can have multiple files. Your asp files are saved as .asp.

Make note of the solution directory when you are creating the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help
How can I end the project and save format aspx ?

Comment: I did not get "end the project". But to clarify aspx files are totally different with asp files. ASP files use Vbscript as their scripting language however aspx files either uses codebehind files for their coding part which can be in c# or vb OR they can also use inline scripting where all the html and code is in same file. Can you throw more light why u want some files as aspx files? how and what your are actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

The .sln format is just a file that will tell Visual Studio what's included in your project, in your project folder all asp files will be included. If you take a look in the projects property window you will find the path to the project where you can find the files.

If you didn't create a project but only a new file it will be saved as the format you picked in the new file wizard.

You are talking about C#, then your files will have the aspx extension not .asp.
And no it doesn't have anything to do with that you're working with the Facebook API.

Please remove the asp.net-mvc tag in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help
How can I end the project and save format aspx ?

Comment: If you only have one open file that you want to save as [filename].aspx, chose "save file as" in the menu and pick the " *. * " in the "save as type" dropdown box, then write the filename of your file and end it with the .aspx extension like "filename.aspx". If you have a project open in wrong language I believe you will have to start a new project in the right format (a new asp.net in C# project) and copy the code that you already wrote into these new files.